# Branch.IO deferred link contains firebase data (Migrating from Firebase to Branch.io)

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, branch.io

We are migrating our React Native app from Firebase deep links to Branch.io links. All scenarios work except one: when a user opens a link **on iOS** and doesn't have our app opened, we don't get all the branch.io data after installation.

Here is our RN code:

```
import branch, { BranchSubscriptionEvent } from 'react-native-branch';

useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = branch.subscribe((value: BranchSubscriptionEvent) => {
          console.log('value', value);
          //more handling of the link
        };
    
        return unsubscribe;
      }, [...dependencyList]);
```

The object, which is logged into the console when **installed on iOS through the link** is:

```
{
    "error": null,
    "params": {
        "+non_branch_link": "com.ourapp.app://google/link/?request_ip_version=IP%5FV4&match_message=No%20pre%2Dinstall%20link%20matched%20for%20this%20device%2E",
        "+is_first_session": true,
        "+clicked_branch_link": false,
        "+rn_cached_initial_event": true
    },
    "uri": "com.ourapp.app://google/link/?request_ip_version=IP%5FV4&match_message=No%20pre%2Dinstall%20link%20matched%20for%20this%20device%2E"
}
```

When we open the same link on Android or when the iOS app is **already installed**, we can see

```
{
    "error": null,
    "params": {
        "~channel": "App",
        "+is_first_session": false,
        //more fields...
        "~feature": "Signup",
        "~campaign": "Refferal",
        "deeplinkURL": "our custom data to handle link",
        "~tags": [
            "referral"
        ]
    },
    "uri": null
}
```

The link was created VIA Branch.io API with payload

```
{
    "data": {
        "$desktop_url": "https://ourdomain.com",
        "deeplinkURL": "our custom data to handle link"
    },
    "channel": "App",
    "campaign": "Referral",
    "feature": "Signup",
    "tags": [
        "referral"
    ],
    "branch_key": "{{branchKey}}"
}
```

In terms of Branch.IO configuration, we have both **Universal Links and NativeLink™ disabled**.

Any idea why we are getting these strange params, after iOS installation from the Quick link?